# Electrostatics conducting surface

Tags: electrostatics

Are there cases in electrostatics where a conducting surface is NOT an equipotential surface? Please give an example.

Comment: Of course there are none.

Comment: put a point charge on the surface, then the potential exactly at the point charge location is ? XD

Answer (score 1):

No, because there can never be a non-zero electrostatic field inside a conductor. This is simply due to the very definition of electrostatics itself. By definition, a conductor contains free charges which can move under the effect of an electrostatic force. So *if* there was a non-zero electric field, charges would start moving and the problem wouldn't be electrostatic anymore. The fundamental assumption of electrostatics itself is that all charges have reached a stable equilibrium and there are no dynamics involved. 
Now since the electric field is zero inside, the potential difference between two arbitrary points on the conductor is:
$$\Delta\phi_{AB} = -\int_A^B d\mathbf x \cdot \mathbf E(\mathbf x) = 0$$
i.e. the conductor is an equipotential surface.

This is in contrast to electrodynamics, where a non-zero electric field can indeed exist inside a conductor (provided it has finite conductivity). This non-zero field is in fact directly proportional to the electric current inside ($\mathbf E \propto \mathbf J$).

Answer (score 1):

For example, the conductor is not an equipotential volume if there are forces of inertia and if we consider the equilibrium in the rotating reference frame. For example, in the case of a conductor rotating about an axis.

The equilibrium condition is $q\overrightarrow{E}+m{{\omega }^{2}}r\overrightarrow{{{e}_{r}}}=0$ in cylindrical coordinates.

The electric field, the density of volume and surface charges are not zero. The case of a sphere is easily calculable but I do not think the effect is measurable ?